# Serve resources from a consistent URL + "?" at end of URL

Tags: wordpress, url, google-pagespeed, yslow, gtmetrix

I know others have danced around this but my question is a little more specific and I have not seen the answer anywhere online.

When I check GTMetrix I get "Serve resources from a consistent URL". The thing is, the two URl's that show are the same except one ends with a question mark. An example would be https://stackoverflow.com/ and https://stackoverflow.com/?

Also additional information: I am using Wordpress with GoDaddy hosting.

Where does this question mark come from and how can I get everything to pull from one URL?

Any help or suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Question mark indicates end of URI resource and starting a query (usually with some params). When adding an empty query to your URI you're actually not changing the request in any way, nor effecting it in any way, so there is nothing to worry about - server will simply ignore it ... About your second question - 'how can I get everything to pull from one URL' - I really don't understand what you mean :)

Comment: Hi Angel, thanks for your response. When I run a speed test on GTMetrix I get "Serve resources from a consistent URL". And it will show the two URL's (one ending with the "?") as the culprit. So instead of having it pull from two different URI's I guess my question is how do i get it to just pull from one or a consistent URL?